# Python Json dictionary groupby

Tags: python, json, group-by

I have a JSON dictionary that looks like this:

```
{
    "4110910046949343232" : {
      "-Mikguh9AR8GCLKzhJSn" : {
        "isViewed" : false,
        "likes" : 0,
        "sender" : "qU0h3LDSPhTdSPxiYGg48XbOWeF2",

      },
      "-MikkIp4kGFJ7cBDOjFs" : {
    
        "isViewed" : false,
        "likes" : 0,
        "sender" : "AD7KVpEwLebwwNHgGEiaRCFAcNk2",

      },
      "-MikkWBnYjIlGNx8CsoE" : {
        "isViewed" : false,
        "likes" : 0,
        "sender" : "OOZr0CWul6g8iUhL2LtIIcrHfnb2",
      },
      "-MikkmS8a41C4Bjr3znn" : {
        
        "isViewed" : false,
        "likes" : 0,
        "sender" : "OOZr0CWul6g8iUhL2LtIIcrHfnb2",
      }
    },
    "4110911931097808896" : {
      "-MhxR1MHsDJ1VqJYo53N" : {
        
        "isViewed" : false,
        "likes" : 0,
        "sender" : "qU0h3LDSPhTdSPxiYGg48XbOWeF2",
    }
```

..........................................................................

I want to groupby using the key `'sender'` such that it looks like this:

```
{
   "4110910046949343232":{
      "qU0h3LDSPhTdSPxiYGg48XbOWeF2":{
         "-Mikguh9AR8GCLKzhJSn":{
            "isViewed":false,
            "likes":0,
            "sender":"qU0h3LDSPhTdSPxiYGg48XbOWeF2"
         }
      },
      "AD7KVpEwLebwwNHgGEiaRCFAcNk2":{
         "-MikkIp4kGFJ7cBDOjFs":{
            "isViewed":false,
            "likes":0,
            "sender":"AD7KVpEwLebwwNHgGEiaRCFAcNk2"
         }
      },
      "OOZr0CWul6g8iUhL2LtIIcrHfnb2":{
         "-MikkWBnYjIlGNx8CsoE":{
            "isViewed":false,
            "likes":0,
            "sender":"OOZr0CWul6g8iUhL2LtIIcrHfnb2"
         },
         "-MikkmS8a41C4Bjr3znn":{
            "isViewed":false,
            "likes":0,
            "sender":"OOZr0CWul6g8iUhL2LtIIcrHfnb2"
         }
      }
   },
   "4110911931097808896":{
      "qU0h3LDSPhTdSPxiYGg48XbOWeF2":{
         "-MhxR1MHsDJ1VqJYo53N":{
            "isViewed":false,
            "likes":0,
            "sender":"qU0h3LDSPhTdSPxiYGg48XbOWeF2"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

..........................................................................

I've tried using itertools with no success. How can I efficiently achieve this?